# How to use same function for buttons created using loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am learning JSP and javascript and I am facing difficulty in understanding the below concept. I am trying to add multiple buttons to the HTML page using for loop and I wanted to take the functionality for each button in one function in Javascript. Please find the code below:

```
<%
BookDetails book=new BookDetails();
ArrayList<String> booktitle=book.Display();
System.out.println("In JSP page");
%>
<%for(int i=0;i<booktitle.size();i++){ %>
<h2>
<%=booktitle.get(i) %></h2><br>
<button onclick="cart()" class="books" >Add to cart</button>

<% } %>

<script>
function cart(){
    alert("Hi");
}
</script>
```

My Question is "Add to Cart" button will be created for every value in the table. When the button is clicked, it should retrieve the name for that book title alone. Could you please help me in that using Javascript?

Comment: What about passing book title on invoking function `cart`? Something like `cart(<%=booktitle.get(i) %>)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can pass the `booktitle.get(i)` into `cart` function, like this

```
<button onclick="cart('<%=booktitle.get(i).replace("'","\\'") %>')" class="books" >
    Add to cart
</button>
```

Here you need to escape single quotation (`'`) to make sure that you get the full book title.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that based off of the code, it might be useful to pass the button number since you are using class names as a parameter into the function. So something like `cart(1)` will return that button. Since you are using a JSP for loop you should be able to get the `ith` element of the button. Then you can get that specific element in JS using

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('class-name')[i]
```

Hope that answers your question!!

P.S I don't know JSP

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on how it can be used in HTML and javascript?

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to add a name of the book you need to pass it in as a parameter.

So:

```
<button onclick="cart(booktitle.get(i))" class="books" >Add to cart</button>
```

Or whatever name of the book you want then later in your script tag:

```
function cart(nameOfBook){
    alert(nameOfBook);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a click event listener on a container element that has all the buttons. Add custom properties to your element(s) where needed and add a `role` custom property to button(s) that add or remove things (have behavior).

Using `role` is better than class because class is used by the browser to make the element look a certain way and can be changed by someone if they want to make the element look different where as `role` is used for behavior (as a convention you need to agree with because it's a user defined property and the browser doesn't do anything with those).

```js
const functionToAddItem = event => {
  const itemID=event.target.getAttribute("x-item-id");
  console.log("this is add item",itemID);
}
const functionToRemoveItem = event => {
  const itemID=event.target.getAttribute("x-item-id");
  console.log("this is remove item",itemID);
}
document.body.querySelector(`[x-role="item-container"]`).addEventListener(
  "click",
  event=>{
    const action = event.target.getAttribute("x-role");
    switch(action){
      case("add-item") :
        functionToAddItem(event);
        break;
      case("remove-item") :
        functionToRemoveItem(event);
        break;
      default:
        //do nothing
    }
  }
)
```

```html
<div x-role="item-container">
  <button x-role="add-item" x-item-id="22">add</button>
  <button x-role="remove-item" x-item-id="22">remove</button>
</div>
```